# Is there safe chemicals for making voice pitch or bass?

Tags: home-experiment, safety

I'm looking for safe experiment that can pitch and bass my voice.finally I find a video that do it but he said "not try in home,ok..?".Is there safe tool or chemicals for Manipulation of the larynx is used to generate a source sound with a particular fundamental frequency.

other my question is about below viedo link:How these chemicals make voice pitch or bass!(Helium and Sulfur Hexafluoride)

Pitch is a perceptual property of sounds that allows their ordering on a frequency-related scale,[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52UAEQfMTtU) or more commonly, pitch is the quality that makes it possible to judge sounds as "higher" and "lower" in the sense associated with musical melodies.

[video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52UAEQfMTtU)

Comment: There are no safe chemicals except oxygen, nitrogen, and water; and even those may kill if used improperly. If you know what are you doing, go on, breathe helium, it's fun. If you don't, don't.

Comment: What if you inhaled both (He + SF6) at the same time?

Comment: This is actually a problem in dealing with undersea habitats for divers: special gas breathing mixtures are used, to reduce or eliminate nitrogen narcosis, “the bends”, etc. The U.S. Navy has naturally done lots of research in this area. Look up gas mixtures for deep sea divers or something along those lines. The problem is that communication is weird: divers sound like Donald Duck and electronic voice correction may be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that helium and sulfur hexafluoride (as shown in the video) will give you the correct sounding "pitch" and "base", it would be fine if done **correctly and safely**.

Helium is incredibly inert and so will not cause any sort of toxicity. It is also a very light gas, so it will exit your lungs quickly. Just do not breath only helium, or for a long time or you could suffocate. Make sure to get lots of normal air.

Sulfur Hexafluoride is also rather unreactive, but more dangerous. This is because it is heavy and will tend to stay in your lungs. Only use it for a short period of time, or **you can asphyxiate**. While the same goes for helium, it tends to exit your lungs more easily.

The actual mechanism that causes them to work is based of how dense they are. It does not change the pitch, however. Instead, it changes something called timbre. This is basically the fact the helium allows sound to travel much faster through it, so it is a similar affect to playing a video at a faster speed.

Sulfur hexafluoride does the exact same thing, except it is much denser and does not allow sound to travel through it very quickly.

If you want to do this, be careful! You can suffocate, especially with sulfur hexafluoride.

Comment: Unless you're upside down?

Comment: Ehm, well I guess so.

Comment: Xenon will also work, but it can act as an anaesthetic so would not be safe if used unsupervised. Short exposure is probably OK.

Answer (score -2):

A  possible safe way to inhale helium is to mix it with 20% oxygen.

Likewise, mix sulfur hexafluoride with 20% oxygen.

Comment: Possible safe is not good enough.

Comment: You can't just have it be possible,it has to be confirmed to be safe otherwise accidents are going to happen.